# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer comandos de slash en discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Mi objetivo es que se puedan utilizar comandos por el uso del slash de discord.py, pero por más que lo intento no lo logro. ¿Hay algún error en mi código?
Cabe recalcar que recorté el código aquí para poder publicarlo, el resto es solo información de prefijo y token.

```
intent = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= bot_prefix, intents=intent)
client = discord.Client(intents=intent)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
#comandos
@bot.command(name="ping",description="El bot hace ping")
async def saludar(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('Pong!')

@tree.command(name = "test", description = "testing") 
async def first_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Hola')
#eventos
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    print("Ready!")
#Run bot
bot.run(bot_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que proporcionas parece estar bien escrito y debería permitir el uso de comandos por medio del prefijo que has establecido. Sin embargo, no veo que hayas configurado el manejo de comandos por medio del slash (/).

Para permitir el uso de comandos por medio del slash, debes agregar lo siguiente al inicio de tu código:

```
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild_ids = [your_guild_id]
    await bot.application_command_bulk_upsert(guild_ids, [tree])
```

En la línea guild_ids = [your_guild_id], debes reemplazar your_guild_id con el ID de tu servidor. Luego, debes agregar el siguiente decorador al inicio de tus comandos:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="ping", description="El bot hace ping")
async def saludar(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

Para manejar los comandos por medio del slash, debes agregar el siguiente decorador al inicio de la función que maneja tus comandos:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="testing")
async def first_command(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.send('Hola')
```

Con estos cambios, deberías poder manejar comandos por medio del prefijo que has establecido y también por medio del slash (/).